# Overlapping element in Flexbox in Safari

Tags: css, flexbox

can someone help me with Flexbox in Safari please?

When I resize the browser, the `.div` element inside of the section is overlapping.

I looked at another threads and saw this some -webkit- prefixes, and i tried to stick them where i thought it could work, but had no success.

Here is my `[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reeoqG][1]`, and see image attached for reference.

Thanks a lot in advance, this site is super helpful.

[image]

Comment: maybe a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276

Comment: thanks! I currently use safari 9 and did all this prefixing, and this did not fix the problem.

Comment: i forked your pen and activated autoprefixer, check if it works now and if it does click "view compiled" in css window and see syntax generated http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxxmvm in additionnal to link of Michael_B

Comment: thanks GC, but nothing. Still same overlap effect.

Comment: Please post all relevant code in your question. A link to another site doesn't adhere to SO guidelines. If the link changes or dies, this question loses all reference value. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Guys, I hosted this page, can you please have a look? http://gibtri.club/team.html